# How to get results of subcategories also?(WP Rest Api v2)

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api

We can get posts from a category using below request

```
    `/wp/v2/posts?categories=1&search=somequery`
```

It only gives results from category(1) only. How can we get results from category(1) and from all subcategories of category(1) also? Than You.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has what you want https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/314152/49962

WP already does this out of the box thanks to the include_children parameter of tax_query which is true by default.

So you do not need to tell it the sub-terms, just do something like this:

```
/wp/v2/posts?categories=1
```

Where `categories=1` is the parent category ID

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do an additional call to find the IDs of the subcategories – there is no way to get posts from subcategories by only including the parent category in the search.

```
/wp/v2/categories?parent=ID&per_page=0&
```

This call will return an array of category objects, grab the IDs of those objects and pass them to your request for posts:

```
/wp/v2/posts?categories=1,A,B,C,D&search=somequery
```

Comment: So I have to add all categories or subcategories id as you mention above.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Is there any other way that I can achieve this?