# Rest Api How to get results of child categories with one api call

Tags: plugin-development, query-posts, rest-api

Example:

If I have a parent category 1 with child categories 2,3,4 etc

instead of a call like this:

```
/wp/v2/posts?categories=1,2,3,4
```

i want a call like this (imaging code)

```
/wp/v2/posts?categories=1&includeallchilds=true
```

that will include all articles from the child and sub-child of 1.

how is this possible? I don't want my application make 2 api calls to find all childs of the categories of 1..

this query can done what i need, but i cant include this on rest api call,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => '1',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Taxonomy terms are already inclusive thanks to the `include_children` parameter which is true by default. You should not need to pass the child terms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WP can already do this out of the box thanks to the `include_children` parameter of `tax_query` which is true by default.

While it is false by default for REST API parameters, it can be turned back on using a tax query, so you do not need to tell it the sub-terms.

[Here's an example taken from the official Make WP blog](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/02/23/rest-api-changes-in-wordpress-5-7/), just do something like this:

```
const query = {
    categories: {
        terms: [ 3, 5, 7 ],
        include_children: true,
    },
};
wp.apiFetch( { path: wp.url.addQueryArgs( '/wp/v2/posts', query ) } );
```

Which generates a URL that looks like this:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories[terms][0]=3&categories[terms][1]=5&categories[terms][2]=7&categories[include_children]=true&_locale=user
```

Notice

Comment: is including also subcategories of subcategories etc ???

Comment: yes, that's also how category archives work. Parent/Child Categories are more like nested boxes than just a way to organise categories

Comment: As of version 5 - this no longer applies.

Comment: @Corfitz. updated, the answer already contained the solution, so I just declared `include_children` explicitly

Comment: Still doesn't work for me :/ - I have had to add a custom function in my child theme's `functions.php` file: https://gist.github.com/imCorfitz/1e86b82d2edb81c788db3c8adac6746b

Comment: @Corfitz. you have to do a tax query, see my update along with the link to the make WP .org official blog

Answer (score 1):

Just stumble on this because I was looking for the solution to same issue.
Don't know if it was changed but it no longer works (if ever was).
Now, you have to make call to categories endpoint `/categories?parent="parent_cat_id"` in order to get list of child categories, then feed that info into another call (posts) `/posts?categories="1,2,3,4.."&...`

Answer (score 0):

as Tom mentioned in the previous answer, append these queries to the rest API query. for me, it working.

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page=10&categories[terms][0]=<category_id>&categories[include_children]=true
```

Replace `<category_id>` with your actual category id

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/258895)